# Which Lens is better to use for portrait photography?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, portrait

Currently am using Canon EOS 600D with 18-55 mm lens. I am concentrating on portrait photography . i need some suggestions for the lens that i can use for it.

Answer (score 3):

You really can't go wrong with a 50mm f1.8, especially if you're just starting out.

Comment: I'd agree with this -- the 1.6x crop on the 600D will make for an 80mm effective focal length which is flattering.

Comment: Unless you want to use it more than twice. OK, that is a *little* hyperbolic. But the 50mm f/1.4 is much more durable and has a much more usable manual focus ring which is handy for portraiture.

Comment: @MichaelClark google Canon 50 f/1.4 focus ring failure, it's a widely reported issue. You can buy about three 1.8s for the price of a 1.4...

Comment: @MattGrum You are the only person I've ever discussed the 50mm f/1.4 that says this is a problem with that lens. I know lots of people who use it and have never had an issue with the focus ring. On the other hand, I do know several who have had 50mm f/1.8 mounts crack into several pieces.

Comment: @MattGrum google Canon 50 f/1.8 broke and you get just as many responses.

Comment: @MichaelClark the point is you can have your 50 f/1.8 break, throw it away and buy a new one, *twice*, and still have more money than if you bought the 1.4. Upgrading to the 1.4 for reliability is slightly ironic as whilst it's perhaps not as fragile as the 1.8 it's still one of the most unreliable EF lenses due to the focus clutch mechanism Canon employed instead of a proper ring USM for focussing. A better choice would be to buy a Sigma 50mm f/1.4 from a reputable retailer and keep sending it back 'till you get one that focusses properly.

Answer (score 1):

For portrait you can look at lenses of focal length between 70 to 200mm. The depth of field produced at this focal length will help in separating your subject from background and also help in flattening the subject.

That being said, there are portrait shooter who get very amazing portrait from using wide angle lens. It all depend on the style or 'look' you are trying to achieve.

But 70 to 200mm is a good place to start.

hope it helps

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this. A 70 lens on a 1.6 crop camera is quite long and you'll have to stand pretty far back. But all this is explained in several other questions/answers already.